# Pyinstaller Error when running the exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote python script which include tkinter, sqllite3, matplotlib and other libraries. When I bundle the script to exe file by using pyinstaller, it's finished successfully but when I run the exe file it's giving me this error:
[image: the error I get]

Need to mention that I don't use any library name babel.
I also add my code to the application below:

```py
# Core PackAages
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkintertable import TableCanvas, TableModel
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fpdf import FPDF

#background


# Database
import sqlite3
import csv
```

Comment: Please add your code, command you use and error message as text, do not use images.

Comment: I have done it :)

Comment: You say your code doesn't import `babel`, but it imports `tkcalendar` and it appears that `tkcalendar` imports `babel`. Look in the `pyinstaller` docs for advice on what to do about hidden imports. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post by removing the code, it is relevant to the question and helpful for people who might come to your post in the future with similar problem. Check out [the licence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), you agree with sharing your code when posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have similar problem as [here](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/32). The solution is simple, add hidden import:

```
pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import babel.numbers script.py
```